# GPG installation got messed up, can't fix

Tags: software-installation, gpg

My GPG installation got messed up, after trying to do some experiments as follows:

```
echo "trust" > "/proc/self/fdinfo/27"
echo "trust" > "/proc/self/fdinfo/26"
echo "trust" > "/proc/5639/fd/0"
echo "trust" > "/proc/5639/fd/1"
echo "trust" > "/proc/5639/fd/2"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/2"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/3"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/4"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/5"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/6"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/7"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/8"
echo -e -n "trust\n" > "/proc/5639/fd/2"
```

The number 5639 is a process id of `gpg --edit-key "Dor"`.
As for now, every time I try to do something, a weird error appears. Example:

```
$ gpg
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
gpg: processing message failed: eof
```

( I was just entering to the `gpg` program and then pressed CTRL+D.
The last line is abnormal: *'gpg: processing message failed: eof'* )

I've tried reinstalling by:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnupg
sudo apt-get install gnupg
```

Also I deleted manually the folder ~/.gnupg

But still the strange error appears.

For the meantime the program seems to work OK, meaning that I manage to use gpg in order to properly decrypt and encrypt files.
But this error disturbs me very much and I would like to fix it.

---

**Edit #1 (22 Sep, 18:41 UTC):**

Here's another command that I entered and the resulting error message received from `gpg`:

```
$ gpg --delete-secret-key "Dor"
gpg: key "Dor" not found: eof
gpg: Dor: delete key failed: eof
```

Comment: The `/proc` filesystem is ephemeral, have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Also, why not just `kill` that process?

Comment: Why do you consider it abnormal that gpg can't process an empty message when given no instructions specifying what it should do with it?

Comment: @dawud: Yes, also tried rebooting. The process wasn't exist, so couldn't `kill` it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I never encountered a message like that, and after having the experiments - the message was shown almost every time I used `gpg`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an error, everything is fine. It just doesn't have anything to do because you didn't specifiy e.g. `--encrypt`. I can reproduce it on my machine:

```
martin@martin ~ % LANG=C gpg
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
gpg: processing message failed: eof
```

Try instead:

```
gpg --encrypt --armor -r <your GPG email adress>
```

and you shouldn't get an error, but instead some `BEGIN PGP MESSAGE` output.

Comment: Thank you. I don't remember ever encountering this error message so I thought that I messed things up. +1 and accepted answer.